# Horizontal and vertical scrolling in android recycler view

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a requirement where I need to have horizontal scrolling and vertical scrolling in a recycler view. It is based on the type of data that is coming from server. If the response from server is having first element as an array, i need that to be in a horizontal scrolling list and if the second element is a single object, then i need to show it in card. Similarly the order changes and should reflect in the UI. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`LayoutManager` is the class that layout views in `RecyclerView`. So change `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(LayoutManager)` if you want to change layout. In your case, if you use `LinearLayoutManager`, do this by calling:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = ...
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

//when you want horizontal
layoutManager.setOrientation(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);

//when you want vertical
layoutManager.setOrientation(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
```

Comment: setOrientation have only orientation parameter. your solution not working for me

Comment: @NaveedAhmad you are right. Api has changed. Updated my code