# Vertical and Horizontal scrolling list or grid in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I am working in an android app that I need to build an vertical scrolling list that each item is also a horizontal list. However each item has its independent horizontal scroll. Even some items could not have.

I have been looking for solutions but I only see vertical OR horizontal lists. Or grids like in the TwoWayView.

I am looking for something like the mix from the following image:

[image: Vertical and Horizontal scrolling list and grids]

Is that possible in Android? Because my data is an array of arrays.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is. Check out this thread to get you started : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31338400/horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling-in-android-recycler-view and also this: http://lucasr.org/2014/07/31/the-new-twowayview/

Comment: not sure about last one image with horizontal other will be possible using recyclerview and its various layout managers with scrolling vertical or horizontal https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Comment: It is because the data I receive is dynamic, there is no fixed size either vertically or horizontally...

Comment: As @Pavan said, You can achieve this by using vertical RecyclerView, where each item is horizontal RecyclerView.

Comment: @traninho If you use a vertical RecyclerView with horizontal RecyclerViews within it won't scroll vertically when the scroll start touch point is on the horizontal items; it only scrolls horizontally (by default). You have to setNestedScrollingEnabled(false) on the inner horizontal RecyclerView to get a scrolling behavior that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, this question helped me: [Nested Recycler view height doesn't wrap its content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649406/nested-recycler-view-height-doesnt-wrap-its-content)

Thanks for the comments.